# Failed to create database in hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I'm using Hive with mysql. Creating database in mysql worked. Somehow could not create database in Hive. The error shows SemanticException like below. Is there anything that I missed? I've tried a few suggested solutions but still couldn't fix it.

[image]

Comment: Try `hive --service metastore`

Answer (score 2):

It seems, the hive metastore service is not started.  After you configure the meta store in hive-site.xml, start the service with below command.

```
hive --service metastore
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by initialising hive metastore database

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -initSchema -dbType $databaseType
```